# Signing and timestamping at the same time VS signing and timestamping later

Tags: java, digital-signature, pkcs#11, trusted-timestamp

I'm building a digital signature module that must conform to EU digital signature directives.

I'm starting from an old but well-working Java module to sign documents in `CAdES` format.
Also, the application is made by a client (desktop JAR executable) and a server part. The client has been developed only to interact with smart card that is connected to a USB reader, the rest happens on the web server.

Current signing clients support two ways of signing **and timestamping** a file: I can use "Sign and timestamp" function or I can first sign a document and then timestamp it.

From the legal point of view, both produce the same result.

My question is: from the **techincal** point of view, is it correct to state that when I sign a document with CAdES (RFC 5126, 140 pages I haven't been able to read all) the output file is the same both when I use a combined "sign and timestamp" function or use the two functions in sequence?

Let me rephrase: is it **not possible** according to the standard to have an enclosure that both represents a digital signature and a timestamp?
Does the standard require to timestamp the signed document or vice versa?

What I want to achieve is to sign the document on client side (using smartcard) and then timestamping the file on server (without touching old client code) and producing **the same exact result** as if I was signing and timestamping a file on the client.

Comment: *Signing and timestamping at the same time* - this never happens for a signature and time stamp which are directly related. Either you first time stamp the document and then add that document time stamp the the authenticated attributes which thereafter are signed (this proves that the document existed as is at the given time and the signature was applied thereafter) or you sign a document, then time stamp the raw signature, and then add this time stamp to the unauthenticated attributes of the SignerInfo (this proves the signature happened was applied before the given time). ...

Comment: ... I assume you want to do the latter. This is easy to do in separate applications. (PS: Yes, there are other possible relationships in CAdES, e.g. timestamping validation related information, but the OP seems to be in one of these earlier situations).

Comment: I might rephrase asking "can signing and timestamping be atomic?"

Comment: Those are two distinct signing operations (technically time stamping is a special case of signing) one of which has to follow the other. Thus, the initial operation always cam be separated, so not atomic.